# Alien anime character that can change gender?

Tags: story-identification, anime

What is the older anime where there is I believe is some kind of alien who is trapped inside of a big glass tube/container? Then two guys save them by smashing the console and freeing the being who changes gender from a man into a woman, then goes on to kiss the man who freed them. All I know is that they had green hair and touched hands on the other side of the glass like they were in love or something.

Answer (score 4):

Kimera 1996
[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimera_(manga))

> It focuses on a man named Osamu, who falls in love with an androgynous vampire-like man named Kimera, being held by the Air Force and hunted by two other vampires.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlN3Q.jpg) One vampire wishes to use Kimera for his/her hermaphroditic nature as the mother to revive their dying race, while another wishes to kill Kimera to save him/her from a fate Kimera did not desire.

[image]

Comment: Posting copyright infringing links is a no-no